# Edits Take Place Immediately for Verified Users

Tags: feature-request, editing, suggested-edits, privileges

I like editing posts, I'm reasonably good at $\LaTeX$, as well as grammar, I have a [PhD in Mathematical Physics from Virginia Tech](http://scholar.lib.vt.edu/theses/available/etd-06302007-091322/unrestricted/FinalDraft.pdf), and it's kind of annoying that my edits need to be reviewed. I'm not terribly interested in the +2 for each edit. I was wondering if M.SE could implement a feature whereby users with advanced degrees and perhaps demonstrated $\LaTeX$ abilities could get the edits-take-place-immediately privilege through some sort of vetting process before the 2k mark, at which point I'd be fine with turning off the +2 as a deterrent for some folks who would want it trivially.

Thoughts?

Comment: If one is truly inclined, obtaining a 1000 points is something that can be done in a couple of weeks without too much effort. If you're interested in editing without oversight, put that week or two into answering questions, get those remaining 902 points, and get on with it. No need to introduce these complications to the system (which is not ideal anyway).

Comment: There are some considerations to editing that come from participation in the Community, so earning the privilege of unreviewed editing through participation makes sense.  Edits often involve getting clarification from an OP, and the ideal is to encourage an OP to learn the mechanics by doing these themselves, so an unbridled enthusiasm for doing edits is not an unalloyed blessing.

Comment: "Edits Take Place Immediately for Verified Users":  such a feature already exists, and the determination of "verified users in terms of such editing" is the accumulation of 2K rep.

Answer (score 17):

First, as a moderator I would not be too happy about vetting such applications.
Beyond just the added workload, there will be clearly good cases like yours, but then there will be *other* cases. Extrapolating from related experience, some will just not take "no" for an answer and this will be one more source of friction.

Second, as a user I would point out that only knowing how to typeset and the math are not quite enough to be a good editor. There are a few things specific to this site (both technically and sociologically) and I feel that it does make sense to be forced to use the site for a while before being allowed to edit.

Comment: (+1) especially for the second paragraph - competence in math and latex and grammar have historically *not* implied competence as an editor or SE contributor.